# Ookii.Dialogs - making sure another dialog appears above Progress dialog

Tags: wpf, c#-4.0, modal-dialog

If you're unfamiliar with **Ookii.Dialogs**, I suggest you [look at this web page](http://www.ookii.org/software/dialogs/) first. It is *open source* and you can find source code, compiled binary, documentation and sample app as a download there.

In my application, I'm using **Ookii.Dialogs.Wpf.ProgressDialog** to *ShowDialog(this)* a progress dialog that does some processing on files (*this* is always the application's main window). As expected, the progress dialog takes about a second before it actually becomes visible (even if it is already doing the processing of my files).

In the *DoWork* thread of the progress dialog, I'm also checking whether the output files already exist and asking the user whether to overwrite each file or skip the output. I use **Ookii.Dialogs.Wpf.TaskDialog** to *ShowDialog(this)* a *"Task Dialog with Command Links"* (looks like [this](http://i.msdn.microsoft.com/dynimg/IC151613.jpg)) and ask the user the overwrite question -- except when the OS doesn't support it, I fall back to a regular *MessageBox* (**the problem applies to the message box as well**).

> The problem occurs when my application finds an existing file right at the beginning of the progress dialog's *DoWork* thread. When the task dialog appears asking user whether to overwrite:
>
> **Expected behavior:** The task dialog must stay on top. When the progress dialog appears (after 1s delay), it must appear behind the task dialog.
>
> **Actual behavior:**  The task dialog does not stay on top. When the progress dialog appears after 1s delay), it appears on top of the task dialog.

The actual behavior does not occur in subsequent overwrite requests when the progress dialog is already visible. The task dialog appears correctly on top of the progress dialog for the subsequent ones, although the user can switch back and forth the two dialogs (just can't switch to the main window from either of them).

I'm looking for this:

- **Best solution:** Make the task dialog appear modal **on the progress dialog**. If the user tries to switch to progress dialog, user must not be allowed to do so.
- **Second best:** Make the first appearance of task dialog remain on top even when the progress dialog appears after the 1s delay.

I'm **not** looking for the following:

- Set the always-on-top flag of task dialog. I don't want the task dialog to appear always-on-top of every window on user's computer.
- Add a delay before task dialog's appearance. I have tried *Thread.Sleep()* even in a loop, it simply hangs the execution of everything and doesn't solve the problem.
- Wait till the progress dialog appears before showing the task dialog. Could work in theory, except I didn't find a way to know if the progress dialog has appeared or not.
- Make the dialogs modeless. I want them both to be modal. (Besides I have tried making them modeless; it doesn't help solve the problem.)
- A solution that works *only* for the task dialog. It must work for the regular message box as well.

Comment: The way to solve the problem would be to use the progress dialog's window handle as the parent of the task dialog. Unfortunately, Ookii.Dialogs doesn't currently expose that functionality (mainly because I didn't think there was any way to get it when I wrote this library; turns out there is an undocumented way).

Comment: @Sven `:)` Glad to hear from you!! Can I apply that undocumented way in my own source code to get the progress dialog's window handle? Or do you have to use it inside Ookii.Dialogs itself to expose the handle to me? Also, would you want to do it anytime soon? Thanks!

Comment: You would need to modify the Ookii.Dialogs source code. I'll look into making these modifications.

Comment: There is an additional problem in implementing that solution. The `MessageBox.Show` method, as well as the `TaskDialog`, require a `Window` instance as their parent. I can retrieve and expose the progress dialog's window handle, but I can never turn it into a `Window`. I can of course change TaskDialog to accept a non-`Window` parent, but this isn't possible for `MessageBox`.

Comment: Hmm, what will be the Type of the progress dialog's windows handle? Why can't it be `Window` or be cast to `Window`? Would be nice if you can give me a link to the undocumented way you're going to use (if there is any). Thanks @Sven

Comment: It would be an `IntPtr`, a native Win32 window handle. There is no way to get a WPF `Window` from that because that has much more functionality and the progress dialog simply isn't WPF. The way to get the handle is to cast the `IProgressDialog` interface to an `IOleWindow` get the handle from that.

Comment: @Sven Is there a way to find out if the progress dialog is visible or still waiting for the 1s delay to expire? Perhaps you can implement a read-only boolean property similar to the `IsBusy` property?

Comment: With the Window handle you could use the `IsWindowVisible` API to check if it's visible. I also found a suggestion online that said that once you have the progress dialog's window handle you can force it to become visible by sending it a `WM_TIMER` message with a timer ID of 1, though that's really getting into the area of implementation details that applications shouldn't really rely on.

Comment: I've done some tests and it seems the *only* way to make this work is to make the progress dialog the owner of the task dialog or message box (which is impossible for the latter unless you use System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox) and to wait until the progress dialog has been shown. The WM_TIMER trick to show it immediately doesn't work; it can be shown immediately with ShowWindow but then it doesn't have an icon at first and still gets activated (thus coming to the foreground) after a few seconds.

Comment: @Sven thanks. I am ready to use System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox if need be. I hope to hear from you on a workable complete solution for this problem.

Comment: @Sven do take note of the answer below. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know this may a little late coming but I just pre-empted a similar problem in my own program and it reminded me of this question.
I used the windows FindWindowEx API function against the task dialogues window title property to find the dialogues window handle, then used my own class to make that an Iwin32Window which can then be used as a parent for a message box or task-dialogue.
the appropriate code is below (VB.NET)

```
    'allows us to use the handle as a window
    class window
        Implements IWin32Window
        private _handle

        public sub new(handle as intptr)
            _handle = handle
        end sub

        Public ReadOnly Property Handle As System.IntPtr Implements System.Windows.Forms.IWin32Window.Handle
            Get
                Return _h
            End Get
        End Property
    end class

    'Declare the needed DLL import
    class NativeMethods
        <DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError:=True, ThrowOnUnmappableChar:=True, CharSet:=CharSet.Unicode, bestFitMapping:=False)>
        Public Shared Function FindWindowEx(hwndParent As IntPtr, hwndChildAfter As IntPtr, lpszClass As String, lpszWindow As String) As IntPtr
        End Function
    end class

    'Make sure you've set a window title when you run your task
    sub runTask()
        dim myDlg as Ookii.Dialogs.ProgressDialog
        'Do what you need to here
        myDlg.WindowTitle = "make sure you set a title"
    end sub
    sub myTask(sender as object, e As System.ComponentModel.DoWorkEventArgs)
         'Checks and balances here
         if fileExists then
              'this is the dialog that's running our task
              Dim dlg As Ookii.Dialogs.ProgressDialog = DirectCast(sender, Ookii.Dialogs.ProgressDialog)
              'Find the window handle
              Dim dlgHandle As IntPtr = NativeMethods.FindWindowEx(IntPtr.Zero, IntPtr.Zero, Nothing, dlg.WindowTitle)
              'make it an Iwin32Window
              dim dlgWindow as new window(dlgHandle)
              'That can then be used as a parent for the message box or the task dialog
              MessageBox.Show(dlgWindow,"The file exists, overwrite?")
         end if
    end sub
```

I'm not really very good at commenting my code or making my explanations understood so If you have any questions about what's going on I'll try and help.

Comment: Perhaps @Sven can take a look at it. Thanks!

Comment: @ADTC: This is basically what I already proposed (except I used `IOleWindow` to get the window handle, which is cleaner than the `FindWindowEx` hack here). The problem is that in WPF, things like `MessageBox` don't take an `IWin32Window` as the parent, they want a `Window`. And it's impossible to create a `Window` instance for anything that's not actually a WPF Window. So while it's doable for Windows Forms, it's not doable for WPF, which is due to a design issue in WPF.

Answer (score 0):

Today I've read the question and found a solution for me. Tried it for TaskDialog, and this ist working. Didn't try with other dialogs.
I wrote a DialogControler to deal with MVVM.
This DialogControlar has a property called 'Owner' which contains the WPF-MainWindow.
Then I use this for invoking (in my case I've been coming from a backgroundthread in the viewmodel) and also set this in ShowDialog.

My Code:

```
using (var dialog = new Ookii.Dialogs.Wpf.TaskDialog())
        {
            dialog.WindowTitle = "My title";
            dialog.MainInstruction = "My text";
            var okButton = new Ookii.Dialogs.Wpf.TaskDialogButton(Ookii.Dialogs.Wpf.ButtonType.Ok);
            dialog.Buttons.Add(okButton);
            Owner.Dispatcher.Invoke(new Action(() => dialog.ShowDialog(Owner)));

        }
```

With this I got a topmost window.